# How to display JupyterLab interface in a FastAPI web app route?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, fastapi, jupyter-lab

I am building a FastAPI web app that is similar to Kaggle and Google Colab.
When the user logs in, the user is routed to the page where JupyterLab interface should show, so that the user can code, execute, save the notebook, etc. It's similar to Kaggle's Code page that displays Jupyter Notebook.

What can I do to achieve this? Please help..!

I've come across displaying static Notebooks for read-only, but I need the interactive console that JupyterLab(or Jupyter Notebook) provides.